# How to dispose() an object that is created in a SELECT...CASE statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net, idisposable

I have a procedure that creates an object based on user input using a SELECT...CASE statement:

```
Dim hash As HashAlgorithm

' Make sure hashing algorithm name is specified.
If (hashAlgorithm Is Nothing) Then
    hashAlgorithm = ""
End If

' Initialize appropriate hashing algorithm class.
Select Case hashAlgorithm.ToUpper()
    Case "SHA1"
        hash = New SHA1Managed()
    Case "SHA256"
        hash = New SHA256Managed()
    Case "SHA384"
        hash = New SHA384Managed()
    Case "SHA512"
        hash = New SHA512Managed()
    Case Else
        hash = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
End Select
```

VS Analyzer complains that I am not disposing of the object in each instance of the SELECT...CASE. So if the user supplied "SHA1" as the algorithm type, then hash is set to a new `SHA1Managed` object. Why would I need to dispose the New `SHA256Managed` class that was never created?

But...If I simply dispose the hash object at the end of the procedure:

```
hash.dispose()
```

Analyzer complains that I haven't disposed the `SHA1Managed`, `SHA256Managed`, `SHA384Managed`, `SHA512Managed`, and `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` objects...of which 4 were never created anyway...

I cannot use `Using hash as HashAlgorithm` because the object has to be instantiated within the `Using` Statement.

I'm thinking that perhaps the code analyzer is simply targeting `New <Object>` statements and that I'm cool, but I wanted to come here for some opinions...

**EDIT:** 
Ok Apparantly it wasn't clear so here is a very simple, small, complete procedure to work with:

```
Public Shared Function HashMe(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal hash2use As String) As Byte()
    Dim myHash As HashAlgorithm
    Select Case hash2use.ToUpper
        Case "SHA1"
            myHash = New SHA1Managed()
        Case "SHA256"
            myHash = New SHA256Managed()
        Case "SHA384"
            myHash = New SHA384Managed()
        Case "SHA512"
            myHash = New SHA512Managed()
        Case Else
            myHash = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    End Select
    Return myHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText))
    myHash.Dispose()
End Function
```

This procedure will work just fine, except that VS Analyzer wants me to dispose all of the `New <Object>` called within the `SELECT CASE`

The answer to wrap it in a Using block is invalid and will not compile.

Comment: Very strange.  I tried it with VS 2012 and ran code analysis on exactly what you put in, and it returned no issues.

Comment: Interesting. They must have improved the analyzer. As I suspected, the problem was with the code analyzer. Thanks for your input. I actually had the post tagged with visual-studio-2010 but someone felt the need to remove that tag @DaveMarkle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this...

```
Public Shared Function HashMe(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal hash2use As String) As Byte()
    Dim returnHash As Byte()
    Select Case hash2use.ToUpper
        Case "SHA1"
            Using (HashAlgorith hashAlgorith = new HashAlgorith())
                returnHash = hashAlgorith.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText))
            End Using
        ... do the same for the other cases ...
    End Select
    Return returnHash
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easiest way to do it would be to just put it in a using block to begin with and create the instance in a function. HashAlgorithm has a method that does exactly what you are doing.

I don't remember the syntax of vb.net, but you would do something like this

```
Using hash as HashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(hashAlgorithm)
    ' use the algorithm here
End Using
```

If you want to roll your own method, it would be something like this

```
Public Shared Function CreateHashAlgorithm(ByVal hash as String)
    Select Case hash.ToUpper
        Case "SHA1"
            Return New SHA1Managed()
        Case "SHA256"
            Return New SHA256Managed()
        Case "SHA384"
            Return New SHA384Managed()
        Case "SHA512"
            Return New SHA512Managed()
        Case Else
            Return New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you would use it like so

```
Using hash as HashAlgorithm = CreateHashAlgorithm(algorithm)
    Byte() data = hash.ComputeHash(whatever)
End Using
```

Now, that said, I don't think you completely understand the case statement because there aren't multiple objects being created, only one, because only one case statement will be matched.

That said, here's the c# version of this that you can run through a converter if you wish.

```
using (HashAlgorithm hash = HashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm))
{
    // use the algorithm
}

// if we want to make our own version of HashAlgorith.Create()
public HashAlgorithm CreateHashAlgorithm(string algorithm)
{
    algorithm = algorithm ?? "";
    switch(algorithm.ToUpper())
    {
        case "SHA1": return new SHA1Managed();
        case "SHA256": return new SHA256Managed();
        // and the rest
        default: return new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    }
}

// and to use it
using (HashAlgorithm hash = CreateHashAlgorithm(algorithm))
{
    byte[] data = hash.ComputeHash(whatever);
}
```

Comment: @Darren...no, that's wrong. It doesn't compile and it breaks the intent of the SELECT...CASE

Comment: it doesn't break the intent, as it's likely that you are accepting bad input and throwing everything else into the MD5, which is still possible if you scrub the data before hand. The code has been updated to fix the trailing ), but if you look at the documentation for [HashAlgorithm.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13.aspx) you'll see that it does exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Well, it doesn't compile, sorry. I added a small, complete procedure to my OP for you to test, but your answer won't compile

Comment: I would be happy to look at a c# answer if you're more comfortable with that

Comment: added what i was talking about and a c# version

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just leave out whatever vb's equivalent of `break` is? The compiler may be complaining that the case statements are falling through into each other and you are just updating the same variable over and over and thus you _would_ be leaving a lot of undisposed instances.

Comment: I understand how the select case works...my biggest question is whether or not visual studio analyzer understands that only one object is created??? Judging by the answers so far, the issue is with the code analyzer. My procedure works fine and is in production, I was taken aback when I decided to run code analyzer and it complained that I wasn't disposing objects that aren't created at runtime

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're being warned about the function is because your HashAlgorithm won't be Dispose()d if an exception gets thrown before .Dispose() is called.

The most straightforward answer, preserving what you've already written, is to call Dispose() in finally{} block like so:

```
    Public Shared Function HashMe(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal hash2use As String) As Byte()
        Dim myHash As HashAlgorithm
try 
        Select Case hash2use.ToUpper
            Case "SHA1"
                myHash = New SHA1Managed()
            Case "SHA256"
                myHash = New SHA256Managed()
            Case "SHA384"
                myHash = New SHA384Managed()
            Case "SHA512"
                myHash = New SHA512Managed()
            Case Else
                myHash = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        End Select
        Return myHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText))
end try 
finally
        myHash.Dispose()
end finally
End Function
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, to wrap it in a try...catch...finally block to insure the object is disposed. It actually IS that way in my complete procedure, which you couldn't have known...but the code analyzer isn't complaining about object "myHash"...it sees THAT is being disposed. It's complaining about (New SHA1Managed) not being disposed, which I think is ridiculous

Comment: I think the `finally` block should check to ensure that `myHash` is non-null before calling `Dispose`, should it not?  Otherwise if an exception occurs at some time prior to `myHash` being written (e.g. because one of the constructors throws) the calling code will see a `NullReferenceException` on the dispose, and any information about the original exception will be lost.